# Discord.py channel “hello” not found

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to create an “echo” command for my bot, here's my code

```
@bot.command(name="echo", help="says something")
async def echo(ctx, channel : None, *, text : str):
    if (message.author.bot):
        return
    if channel == None:
        # if a channel is not specified, send in the same channel where the command was called
        ctx.send(text)

    else:
        channel.send(text)
```

But when I type “!echo hello", I got this error:

```
raise ChannelNotFound(argument)
discord.ext.commands.errors.ChannelNotFound: Channel "hello" not found.
```

What??? Shouldn't “channel” be optional? How do I solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, you give to the bot with this the string `hello`, from which it wants to find a channel.

Also Channel is it's own class, so you would have to build in a function which searches for the channel (discord.utils.get I think).

I think what you want, is to switch description and channel so you don't firstly have to enter the channel.